# How to trigger Job A if Job B has changes in the SCM

Tags: jenkins, svn, triggers, jenkins-plugins

I have two projects on Jenkins project A and project B. B is depending on A and it builds only when A is built. I have configured A with Build Triggers-> Poll SCM so three times a day between 9-5 on working days to check for changes in the SCM of A. If there are changes in project A it initiates the build of A. When A it finishes it triggers the build of B. The problem is that if SCM changes are made only to B and not to A, the A is not triggered. 
How can i have the project A to detect if changes have been made in project B and if they are, then to initiate the build of A?
Has anyone faced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the **Multiple SCMs** option so Project A will trigger when there is a change in repo A **or** repo B

Comment: Thank you very much, that seemed to be working. i will test it in the following days as well.